# HTML5 FileReader() how to get file from drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I am trying to use the FileReader() function to read a file as text and display it back on my webpage - so far, so good. The problem is, instead of allowing the user to select any file off their computer, I want to offer them a specific list of files on the server, via a drop-down menu.
I have no problem populating the drop-down menu with a list of file names. But what I don't know is how to make the file reader take this file name and read the relevant file. I'm guessing the problem is because the file reader expects a file, and is getting a String, but I don't know how to get round this?

I've spent a couple of hours googling and reading tutorials, and they all seem more or less like [this one here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), which relies on using an `<input type="file" . . .>` button.

Can anyone tell me how to do this, or point me to some more extensive/varied tutorials?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to display files from the client, or from the server? If server, you don't need `FileReader`, just make a request and serve the file contents. If client, then how do you get the list of files in a drop-down menu?

Comment: From the server . . . so what you're saying is I should go . . . Ajax? (yes I am VERY new)

Comment: Ajax if you don't want a page transition, yes.

Comment: Righto, back to the tutorial-hunt :-) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :-)